# Can I remove these DNS zones?

Tags: dns-zone, zones, remove, domain-name-system

I manage a server without a cpanel, I installed Webmin on it. And under Bind settings I have these zones:

```
"Root zone" 
"0" 
"0000::1"   
"127.0.0.1" 
"mydomain.com"
"localhost" 
"localhost.localdomain"
```

I am wondering if is safe to remove these zones and only leave "root zone" and "mydomain.com". I am not sure why they are there but on another server I only have these two left and seems to work ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the server is *only authoritative* (i.e. serving your domain to third parties) you may safely remove those zones.

If the server is providing *recursive* DNS lookup service to any client (including to itself[*]) then they should remain to prevent queries for those potential local zones going out to the wider internet.

[*] i.e. if `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

They are there in case something looks up those names and doesn't have entry in their hosts file the way they're supposed to. I don't know what "0" is, but the localhost and loopback IP zones should be there.